# How to delete from table tradecode where I have child without parent?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

problem

How to delete rows from table tradecode where I have childcodevalue without parentcodevalue ?

parentcodevalue and childcodevalue exist on table trade code based on table

MappingCodeValue parentcodevalue and childcodevalue .

so i need to delete records from trade code table that not have parentcodevalue

on table trade code based on table mappingcodevalue

so according to my explain two rows 5,6 on trade code table will be deleted

```
TradeCodeId  PartId CodeType   CodeValue    
5        1444   ECCS-URB    AB666-URB             
6        1931   ECCS-URB    AB778-URB
```

5 and 6 is childcodevalue and not have parentcodevalue rows as AB666-US and AB778-US

so it wrong and i will delete it

but another rows on trade code have parent code value and child code value

according to table mappingcodevalue so that it is correct

so how to write query delete rows that have  childcodevalue and not have

parentcodevalue from trade code

based on value exist on mappingcodevalue

```
drop table #MappingCodeValue
drop table #TradeCode
create table #MappingCodeValue
 (
 id int identity (1,1),
 ParentCodeType  nvarchar(50),
 ParentCodeValue  nvarchar(50),
 ChildCodeType  nvarchar(50),
 ChildCodeValue  nvarchar(50)
 )
 INSERT INTO #MappingCodeValue
 (ParentCodeType,ParentCodeValue,ChildCodeType,ChildCodeValue)
 VALUES
 ('ECCS-US','AB123-US','ECCS-URB','AB123-URB'),
 ('ECCS-US','AB555-US','ECCS-URB','AB555-URB'),
 ('ECCS-US','AB666-US','ECCS-URB','AB666-URB'),
 ('ECCS-US','AB778-US','ECCS-URB','AB778-URB')


 CREATE TABLE #TradeCode
 (
 TradeCodeId int identity(1,1),
 PartId  int,
 CodeType  nvarchar(50),
 CodeValue nvarchar(50)
 )
 insert into #TradeCode(PartId,CodeType,CodeValue)VALUES
 (1222,'ECCS-US','AB123-US'),
 (1255,'ECCS-US','AB555-US'),
 (1222,'ECCS-URB','AB123-URB'),
 (1255,'ECCS-URB','AB555-URB'),
 (1444,'ECCS-URB','AB666-URB'),
 (1931,'ECCS-URB','AB778-URB')
```

**what i try**

```
delete t from #tradecode t 
 left join  #mappingcodevalue pn on t.CodeValue=pn.ParentCodeValue and t.CodeType=pn.ParentCodeType
 where t.CodeValue is null
```

see image modifications
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this query below and give me result i need

```
delete from #TradeCode where PartId
not in (select t.PartId from #TradeCode t inner join #MappingCodeValue m
on t.CodeType = m.ParentCodeType and t.CodeValue = m.ParentCodeValue
where
(t.CodeValue = m.ParentCodeValue and t.CodeType = m.ParentCodeType) or
(t.CodeValue = m.ChildCodeValue and t.CodeType = m.ChildCodeType)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `left join`, so there won't be any record in the result which has `NULL` value for the left table column (`t` in your case, so, no record will have `NULL` for `t.CodeValue`).

You can always check first by selecting the records without `where` clause to see what should be the condition to delete unwanted records.

There won't be any corresponding record in the table `#MAppingCodeValue` as per your join condition and the sample data provided for 4 records in the table `#TradeCode` (please see screenshot below).

[image]

Please check the details in **[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=840389a4cde1a9a72abacc03877297ea)**.

Comment: thanks so what is correct query to delete records 5 and 6 that from trade code

Comment: @ahmedbarbary as per given data, there are 4 records (3,4,5 and 6) in table #TradeCode which don't have matching parentCodeType in table #MappingCodeValue. Why you want only 5 and 6 to be deleted only?

Comment: thank you for reply this is not correct see modifications 
may be query is wrong so that i need help to modify

Comment: can you see image above

Comment: @ahmedbarbary Please add the image in your question.

Comment: @ahmedbarbary can you please suggest on what basis you want to retain the 4 records (TradeCodeIds 3,4,5 and 6) and delete only two records (TradeCodeIds 5 and 6) because as per the given conditions, only records with TradeCodeId 1 and 2 should be retained?